# Why did a mod delete my answer about Google Calendar?

Tags: discussion, moderation

This [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/171423/18147) to my question [How can I change Google calendar to view all 24 hours for each day in the week view mode, without having to scroll?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92640/) was [deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSA6z.png) by a mod.

> Currently, it is not possible to configure Google Calendar so that one may view all 24 hours for each day in the week view mode, without having to scroll. There is no built-in feature implementing that functionality. Google Calendar only allows to change how many days to display. The only options that don't require additional code are zooming out or having some monitor with a portrait ratio.

Why?

Answer (score -4):

## Why

At the time that you self-answered the 7 year old question we were in the midst of discussing it prompted by a duplicate flag I received.

The question was unclear.  In the 7 years it had received only a single answer 4 years ago, but it wasn't the first time it had been suggested as a duplicate. The duplicate target was unfortunately (misleadingly) titled ["Google Calendar view whole day at once"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/41041/) which was why it kept being brought up over the years.  I subsequently edited the title of that particular post to ["Lock calendar view to a certain part of the day"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/41041/) to better reflect its question.

As I worked with you to understand and clarify your own question it eventually became clear that it was not a practical question about using a web app.

Your question could be simplified to the following:

> My screen doesn't have enough vertical height to display all the content I want without it becoming too small to read comfortably (zoomed or unzoomed is not relevant).  Changing nothing, how can I make all the content fit on the screen but not become too small to comfortably read?

The problem has nothing to do with Google Calendar since it applies to any content on your screen whether a web app or otherwise. It also isn't an issue tied to the orientation of the display (portrait/landscape) but rather the resolution of the display in its current orientation. I illustrated this to you with a screenshot of half my display (which is also 16:9 and in landscape orientation) displaying all 24 hours comfortably because my screen is bigger than yours.  If you don't have enough resolution you need to zoom out. If your monitor isn't big enough regardless if you have the native resolution or need to zoom out to simulate it, the rendered text may be too small to comfortably read.

As we neared the end of our discussion I posted the following two comments:

> This question isn't a practical question about using a Web Application. Any web page whose content didn't fit in the viewable area would require zooming or scrolling. Zooming makes it smaller but you don't like it smaller. What kind of solution are you seeking?
> –
> Blind Spots
> ♦
> Jul 24 at 20:52

> FYI the 16:9 aspect ratio of your current display is not an issue.  Your display simply doesn't have the vertical resolution to display 24 hrs at 100% zoom.  You can **[1]**  increase the vertical resolution by rotating the display or replacing it,  or **[2]** decrease the zoom until it fits.   My display is also 16:9: [1:1 screenshot (right half of display)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3937.png) 
> –
> Blind Spots
> ♦
> Jul 24 at 20:52

The question was 7 years old but once you understood it would be closed you rushed to post an answer incorrectly summarizing our discussion.

The question closure and your answer both took place at 20:57 so presumably you posted with seconds to spare and I also deleted it within seconds at 20:58.

I don't believe you should have added and accepted the answer given the circumstances nor is it useful or correct.

I have undeleted the answer and will seek additional guidance from the community for the future.