# Why are questions asking about the actions of one moderator closed by this moderator as opinion-based? Aren't mod decisions supposed to be objective?

Tags: discussion, moderators, meta

Title: Why are questions asking about the actions of one moderator closed by this moderator as opinion-based? Aren't moderation decisions supposed to be objective?

The meta questions:

- [Why was my comment asking the author of an answer to clarify their answer deleted by a mod?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5078/18147)
- [Why was this answer about Google Calendar deleted by one mod?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5083/18147)

asked about the action of one moderator. To my surprise, both questions were closed by the same moderator as "opinion-based".

Why are questions asking about the action of one moderator closed by this moderator as opinion-based? Aren't moderation decisions supposed to be objective?

---

Note: this question is not a duplicate of [Why was my comment asking the author of an answer to clarify their answer deleted by a mod?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5078/18147). Here, it's a question about the closure of the other meta questions. The other question if about the deletion of some comments by a moderator. The two questions are very different.

Comment: Not a duplicate. Here it's a question about the closure of other meta questions.

Comment: I suggest reaching out to the Community Managers about the several closures of meta posts by a moderator. I don’t think it’s right to block the discussion of moderator actions, shutting down community dialogue and input.

Answer (score 6):

As per the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag wiki (emphasis mine):

> Questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often **subjective**. If your question isn't a bug report, feature request, or request for assistance, or question with a concrete answer, it's probably a discussion.

> A discussion question may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and is often **subjective**.

I find the “opinion-based” close reason for a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) meta post to be rather puzzling. Meta site discussions are, by their nature, opinion-based, as they are meant to facilitate dialogue and feedback among the community members. Discussion questions do not always have an objective, clear-cut, right or wrong answer and are usually subjective/opinion-based.

I would appreciate it if those meta posts could be reopened and answered [before Roomba deletes them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/162827), so that the community can understand why these moderator actions are being taken and provide constructive feedback on those actions.